# How to use Keycloak Admin CLI with Ansible on Windows

Tags: ansible, devops, keycloak

I installed Keycloak and created an Admin User via Ansible on a Windows 2016 Server, so far so good.
Now I want to install the Admin API via Ansible in order to configure Keycloak via Ansible as well.
When I run the next 3 commands locally in the command line of the windows machine, all works fine:
1. Install API: run `kcadm.bat` from bin folder

2. Connect to api:`\bin>kcadm config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user keycloak`
   Then I am asked for authentication:
   Logging into http://localhost:8080/auth as user keycloak of realm master
   Enter password: xxxxx
3. Create client:
   `c:\> kcadm create clients -r master -s clientId=my-client-s "redirectUris=[\"http://localhost:8980/myapp/*\"]" -i > clientid.txt`

Can anyone advise how to do this in Ansible?

I run the first command with win command:

```
- name: install admin cli for keycloak
  win_command: 'C:\Install\Keycloak\keycloak-6.0.1\keycloak- 6.0.1\bin\kcadm.bat'
```

I am getting:

```
fatal: [keykloak-ansible]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "C:\\Install\\Keycloak\\keycloak-6.0.1\\keycloak-6.0.1\\bin\\kcadm.bat", "delta": "0:00:01.190629", "end": "2019-05-16 06:42:36.617885", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-16 06:42:35.427256", "stderr": "", "stderr
_lines"
```

Not sure for what is the kcadm.bat required, because from the details its not installing anything.
So I tried to run straight away the authentication command as following:

```
- name: keycloak cli authentication
  win_command: kcadm config credentials --server http://10.128.32.220:8080/auth --realm master --user keycloak --password xxx
 args:
   chdir: 'C:\Install\Keycloak\keycloak-6.0.1\keycloak-6.0.1\bin'
```

But this fails with:

```
fatal: [keykloak-ansible]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "C:\\Install\\Keycloak\\keycloak-6.0.1\\keycloak-6.0.1\\bin\\kcadm config credentials --server http://10.128.32.220:8080/auth --realm master --user keycloak", "msg": "Exception calling \"SearchPath\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Could not
locate the following executable C:\\Install\\Keycloak\\keycloak-6.0.1\\keycloak-6.0.1\\bin\\kcadm.exe
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Anyone ever used Admin CLI with Ansible on Windows?

Thanks
Rina

Answer (score 0):

Not Windows but Linux we are doing same,after keycloak installation we are adding **Realm/Client/User/Group/Mapper** etc from `kcadm` and its very smooth process,One thing you have to remember if you are going kcadm nothing but a admin tool to use Keycloak from command line,so its mandatory to use `kcadm.sh` for linux and `kcadm.bat` for Windows.These are core scripts to run the Keycloak commands from command prompt.

So you have to run command with kcadm.sh or you have to go to the directory of keycloak where `kcadm.bat` and `kcadm.sh` file exist and then run the commands,so in our case we are running shell script file from Ansible and shell script contain commands like this

## STEP1:Enable HTTPS

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config truststore --trustpass keycloak  /opt/keycloak/security/ssl/keycloak.jks
```

## STEP2:Login with client admin-cli

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server https://{{keycloak_server_IP}}:{{keycloak_port}}/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin --client admin-cli
```

## STEP3:Create a new realm TEST

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=SURE -s id="TEST" -s enabled=true
```

1. If your Keycloak running on `HTTPS` then use first command.
2. Login to keycloak with `master` realm .
3. Now after successful login you can run other commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to implement the same in Windows. I have a service provider file which is an XML doc. I want to create clients using keycloak CLI, but unable to do so using the service provider xml file. Though the command that is used to create client is:

`kcadm.bat create clients -r demo -s clientId=adminconsole -s  "redirectUris=[\"https://localhost:8080/admin-web/*\"]" -s protocol=saml`

This command is creating the client but not as it does by importing the file. There may be some additional parameters that needs to be used to provide some more information like values for signing certificate, encryption certificate and all.

For the question asked you can use:

- name: Keycloak Configuration - Create Realm, User, Clients and Set User Password

  ```
  become_method: runas

  become: yes

  vars:

    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"

    ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_password }}"

  ansible.windows.win_command: cmd.exe

  args:

    chdir: '{{ keycloak_bin_path }}'

    stdin: "{{ item.From }}"

  loop:

    - { From: 'kcadm.bat config credentials --server https://localhost:8081/auth --realm master --user {{ keycloak_admin }} --password {{ keycloak_password }}' }

    - { From: 'kcadm.bat create realms -s realm={{ keycloak_realm }} -s enabled=true' }

    - { From: 'kcadm.bat create users -r {{ keycloak_realm }} -s username={{ keycloak_user }} -s enabled=true -o --fields id,username' }

    - { From: 'kcadm.bat set-password -r {{ keycloak_realm }} --username {{ keycloak_user }} --new-password {{ keycloak_user_pass }} -t' }

    - { From: 'kcadm.bat create clients -r {{ keycloak_realm }} -s clientId=adminconsole -s "redirectUris=[\"https://localhost:8080/admin-web/*"]" -s protocol=saml' }
  ```

Comment: "Me too" is not an answer.

Comment: Well I mentioned it because I need assistance with creating client in Keycloak using CLI with attributes. Also I did answer the question what was required. For keycloak I already posted a question to which I have not got an answer yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313664/create-keycloak-client-using-cli-using-service-provider-xml-file

Comment: I have removed the question from this, so it is purely an answer. Feel free to continue editing, but please post questions as a question, rather than merging it into answer spaces.